# ValueError in calculator

Tags: python, calculator

I wonder, if it's possible to show a message "Invalid...", whenever a user tries to input string in `x` or `y` instead of integers?

***Here's the code :***

```
print("Enter a operator first ('+-*/') or 'q' to Exit! ")

while True:
    choice = input("Enter choice (one of these): '+', '-', '/', 'x': ")

    if choice in ('x+-/'):
        x = int(input("First number: "))
        y = int(input("Second number: "))

        if choice == "+":
            print(x, "+", y, "=", x + y)
        elif choice == "-":
            print(x, "-", y, "=", x - y)
        elif choice == "/":
            print(x, "/", y, "=", x / y)
        elif choice == "x":
            print(x, "x", y, "=", x * y)

    elif choice == 'q':
        break

    else:
        print("Invalid choice. Try again.")
```

I tried these code to solve my problem but didn't succeed

```
if x != int:
    print("invalid...")
# And Also
if x == str:
    print ("invalid...")
```

Using these also, doesn't solves my problem:

***Here's the error I get:***

```
x = int(input("First number: "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'as'
```

I guessed it's because I indicated in the beginning that `x =input` must be in integer, but if i take away this `"int"` the whole project won't work and I'll get this error:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

Comment: What you need IS NOT checking the type (btw it is `isinstance(x, int)` but you want ot verify that the string can be converted to int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Use a try/except block as follows:

```py
try:
    x = int(input("First number:"))
    y = int(input("Second number: "))
except ValueError:
    print('Invalid...')
```

Comment: @KnowNothing, you are very welcome.

Comment: @SolomonPByer, updated, good catch! Now it will make sure both `x` and `y` are integers. But the general idea is to take advantage of the exception raised.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
while True:
    choice = input("Enter choice (one of these): '+', '-', '/', 'x': ")

    if choice in ('x+-/'):
        x = input("First number: ")
        y = input("Second number: ")

        if x.isalpha() or y.isalpha():
            print("invalid...")
        else:
            x=int(x)
            y=int(y)

            if choice == "+":
              print(x, "+", y, "=", x + y)
            elif choice == "-":
              print(x, "-", y, "=", x - y)
            elif choice == "/":
              print(x, "/", y, "=", x / y)
            elif choice == "x":
              print(x, "x", y, "=", x * y)

            elif choice == 'q':
              break

    else:
        print("Invalid choice. Try again.")
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you, @sam2611. Could i ask you to explain to me "else x = int(x)", please? It works, but i would just like to better understand the logic here. And can we make it without else statement? If my questions is kinda silly i want you to know that i'm really a debutant :D

Comment: Since the OP wanted to input string and check for it I intended to input string by using x=input( ) , and then I used the int function to convert the string if It was completely a number.                                                     int() function in Python and Python3 converts a number in given base to decimal.

Syntax :

int(string, base)

Comment: Also if we don't do this it is not possible for the program to proceed further as if using x= int( input()) will result in error instead of displaying invalid and continuing the program as soon as someone enters a string.

Comment: I think i understood your answer. Thank you very much, @sam2611, today i learned something new because of you. Have a good day :)

Comment: Your welcome. I also learned about the value error through your question.